# Split string with double quotes in java

Tags: java, string

I have delimited file with records like.

```
val1|"val2"|"val3|val4"|val5
```

I need to split the record so that if the field contains delimiter in between ,it should be quoted.Otherwise ,if field does not contain delimiter(|) ,quote should be omitted.

Output should be like this:

```
col1=val1
col2=val2
col3="val3|val4"
col4=val5
```

I modified answer for similar question to arrive at code below.

```
String testData = "val1|"val2"|"val3|val4"|val5";
        char quote = '"';
        List<String> csvList = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean inQuote = false;
        boolean delimInside = false;
        boolean isPrevQuoted = false;
        ;
        int lastStart = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < testData.length(); i++) {
            if ((i + 1) == testData.length()) {

                if (inQuote && !delimInside) {

                    csvList.add(testData.substring(lastStart + 1, i));
                } else {
                    csvList.add(testData.substring(lastStart, i + 1));
                }
            }
            if (testData.charAt(i) == quote) {
                // if the character is quote
                if (inQuote) {
                    inQuote = false;
                    isPrevQuoted = true;
                    continue; // escape
                }
                inQuote = true;
                continue;
            }
            if (testData.charAt(i) == '|') {
                if (inQuote) {

                    delimInside = true;
                    continue;
                }
                if (isPrevQuoted && !delimInside) {

                    csvList.add(testData.substring(lastStart + 1, i - 1));
                } else {
                    csvList.add(testData.substring(lastStart, i));
                }

                delimInside = false;
                isPrevQuoted = false;
                lastStart = i + 1;
            }
        }
```

I was looking for elegant solution for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that even compile? It shouldn't

Comment: It works here, if I use `String testData = "val1|\"val2\"|\"val3|val4\"|val5";`. What is the question?

Comment: Ya, if you use that, which ISNT in the question. Its obvious he hasnt even tried to run the code

Comment: Sorry.Actually I replaced code testData with sample record while formatting the question.Forgot to escape quotes. Mistake:(

Comment: There's and open source library called OpenCSV which is handy for this type of thing.  It takes a delimiter (in this case pipe) and honors the double quoted strings.  It's open source, so you can see how they break apart the string.  You can find it at http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Mike , my requirement is that quotes should be droppped if the column does not contains the delimiter.Is it available in OpenCSV ?

Comment: Is a regex solution acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are examples of one way of doing it with and without regex. First, split the string by `"`:

```
String test = "1|\"2\"|\"3|4\"|5|\"6|7|8\"";
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String[] strings = test.split("\"");
```

Those are:

```
1|
2
|
3|4
|5|
6|7|8
```

Without regex I use a `StringBuilder` so to not create too many strings. I trim the `|` and pad with `"` when appropriate:

```
for (int i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    if (strings[i].equals("|"))
        continue;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(strings[i]);
    if (strings[i].startsWith("|"))
        builder.deleteCharAt(0);
    if (strings[i].endsWith("|"))
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length()-1);
    if (builder.indexOf("|") != -1)
        builder.append("\"").insert(0, "\"");
    list.add(builder.toString());
}
```

With regex I just need to do the padding with `"` when appropriate:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([^|]+(?:\\|.+)?)");

for (int i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(strings[i]);
    while (m.find()) 
        if (m.group(1).contains("|"))
            list.add("\"".concat(m.group(1)).concat("\""));
        else
            list.add(m.group(1));
}
```

After `System.out.println(list)` both have output of `[1, 2, "3|4", 5, "6|7|8"]`. You can use or not use `String`s instead of `StringBuilder` depending on your specific cases.

Comment: This looks good. I forgot to mention delimiter can appear multiple times in a column

Comment: @arjun You mean `"var1|var2|var3"`? Anything else we need to know?

Comment: That's all the requirement.